# Will 0x10c programming questions be on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, allowed-questions

Stack Overflow [already has a related tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcpu-16), although it appears early questions have been deleted. Should questions about [programming in 0x10c](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt) be on topic on this site?

Comment: I'd imagine is still a bit too early for actual questions regarding the game

Comment: It would help if you provide more context about the game. In general though, from earlier policy questions, if programming is an essential part of the game then it could technically be permissible.

Comment: Is this even a real question?  It seems like a total non-issue at the moment.

Comment: No harm in being proactive.  I'd said it's near-certain that someone will ask a question about this here once the game can be played.  I'd also say the questions should be asked on SO ... programming for a game is still primarily programming.  The effects of doing something (with code) on the game world should be on-topic though.

Comment: Of similar vein is [core wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_War) on topic for gse?

Comment: @NickT The questions will come, it would be good to have an idea of what our policy is before then.

Comment: You posted the wrong tag, SO is using the tag [dcpu-16] for the programming language. As noted, they already have 3 questions on it.

Answer (score 15):

Stack Overflow already has [questions about the DCPU-16 programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dcpu-16).

For those unfamiliar, this is a freaking assembly-level programming language; extremely low level. Here's a recent copy of the [spec](http://0x10c.com/doc/dcpu-16.txt). Any and all questions regarding DCPU-16 are going to require *programmers*, not gamers, to answer them.

*It is a low level programming language*. The fact that it's in a game doesn't change that fact, and unlike Redstone it's not simple enough to be on Gaming over SO. Heck, I'm a professional programmer and the programming in this game sounds like work.

Comment: tl;dr: **NO**...

Comment: mmm, I want this game now...

Comment: Some gamers know several assembler dialects ;)

Answer (score 12):

I think it probably depends on the question.

For instance, if it's "how do I sort things in memory in 0x10c", it's probably for SO, or heck even CodeGolf.SE if you want it small and/or efficient.

On the other hand, if it's something like "how do I make the lights on my ship flash?" it might belong here, even if the answer ends up being `mov 10 [lights]` or something; after all, no amount of programming knowledge will tell you which memory-mapped location controls the ship's lights.

I imagine the split will be similar to the one between Electronics.SE and SO; problems that are purely programming belong on SO, but questions that rely specifically on in-game hardware might have a place here.